# Apply {{plot("Name")}} in TradingView strategy's alert_message

Tags: pine-script

How can I use variable in alert_message in the strategy script?
If that condition is not available, is there any other solutions to use variable other than strategy.xxx variable?

Comment: Could you please edit your question to provide more information on what you're trying to accomplish? It's not really clear. Preferably with an example of your script. This will help the community assisty you more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because strategy alert text can be dynamic, it is much more flexible than `alertcondition()` text in studies. You can use something like this:

```
strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, when=GoLong, alert_message='long slprice=' + tostring(stoploss_long) + ' tradeid=' + tostring(trade_id) +' tp=' + tostring(TakeProfitLevel))
```